# How to save multi line values in textbox into multi rows in sql

Tags: c#

I'm trying to save multi line values in textbox into multi rows in sql.
I have a textbox as shown in below image

http://www.4shared.com/photo/91DD7knd/Multi-textbox.html

After save, I want in data sql as below:

http://www.4shared.com/photo/8yEVRPbV/Data-Sql.html

Comment: Please edit your question to include the picture.

Comment: Why you want to save data in DB with Multiline ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method,
this inserts three lines at a time as comma separated values

```
public void insertRowsToDb(string multiTextString)
{
    int i = 0;
    string insertString = "";
    string[] result = multiTextString.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (string s in result)
    {
        for (i = 0; i = 2; i++)
        {
            insertString = insertString + s+",";
            //Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        insertString = insertString.Substring(0, insertString .Length - 1);//Trim last comma
        insertToDb(insertString);//Your DB insert procedure here
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm trying.